# pls-00402 alias required in select list of cursor to avoid duplicate column names

Tags: oracle, plsql, alias

My cursor :

```
  SELECT xzis.msisdn msisdn, xzis.in_account_number in_Account_number
    FROM xxobw_zte_in_sync xzis
   WHERE NOT EXISTS
                    (SELECT 1
                       FROM hz_contact_points hcp, hz_cust_Accounts hca
                      WHERE hcp.owner_table_id = hca.party_id
                            AND hcp.owner_table_name = 'HZ_PARTIES'
                            AND HCP.PHONE_NUMBER =
                                   SUBSTR (xzis.msisdn, -8)
                            AND NVL (hca.attribute12, 'NIL') =
                                   xzis.in_account_number);
```

I have given alias to all the columns, still facing the issue. ANy suggestions?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a difference piece of code from the one posted.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably about another cursor. This one has no such problems. The problem is, when you're joining two tables, or apply wrong aliases in a subselect, the cursor may at the end return two columns with the same name/alias.

The problem is not that they all need an alias, but that no two columns can have the same alias (the name counting as an alias, when no alias is given). Apparently something like that has happened, but as far as I can tell, it's not in this one.

Comment: you are right.. the problem was with another cursor. thanks for your time!